# problem based on dependent and independent event

Tags: probability

Suppose it we toss 3 coins simultaneously with event E be "three head or three tails" and event F be "at most two head", then by formula
Which is
P(E intersection F)≠ P(E)×P(F)
In the case the condition is satisfied hence they are dependent events but by logic they should be independent of each other.

Comment: "*but by logic they should be independent of each other*"  You should always be skeptical of things being independent of one another.  Intuition can betray you, especially as you are still learning.  You say "by logic" they are, but provide no explanation.  To the contrary, these are both statements involving multiple coins, the same coins at that... and they have nontrivial intersection of an amount difficult to predict with mental arithmetic without having to look more closely.  That would imply to me that they *should* be dependent but would need to check the numbers to be sure.

Comment: Independent events are very specifically those events for which $\Pr(E\cap F)=\Pr(E)\times\Pr(F)$.  No other "*intuitive*" definition suffices as our intuition can fail.  The only way to be sure is to check that equality.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the great explanation 